# Show $\frac14\leqslant P(\min(X,Y)>10)\leqslant\frac12$ for this bivariate normal $(X,Y).$

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I have a question that I've been struggling over. Let $(X,Y)$ have a bivariate normal distribution with $E(X)=E(Y)=10$ and $Var(X)=Var(Y)=16$ and $Corr(X,Y)=1/2.$ The question (and solution) is as follows:

[image: Solution]

I understand why $P(\min(X^*,Y^*)>0 = P(X^* > 0,\, Y^*>0).$ This is because if the minimum value is greater than $0,$ then both $X$ and $Y$ will be greater than $0.$ However I don't understand the steps after this on proving the lower/upper bounds. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "However I don't understand the steps after this on proving the lower/upper bounds." Which ones?

Comment: I have formatted your question and title for easier reading. Please check that your meaning is intact. Also, please be specific about any step(s) you still don't understand. While this Question is 'on hold' (I assume because you have not been specific and shown what you have tried), no further answers can be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $Z \sim Norm(0,1)$ because 
$$0 = E(Y^*) = E[(1/2)X^* + (\sqrt{3}/2)Z] = 0 + (\sqrt{3}/2)E(Z)$$
and
$$1 = V(Y^*) = V[(1/2)X^* + (\sqrt{3}/2)Z] = (1/4) + (3/4)V(Z).$$

Also, $X^* > 0$ and $Z > 0\,$ imply $(1/2)X^* + (\sqrt{3}/2)Z > 0.$
which takes care of the $\ge$ in the long display ending with $1/4.$

The following simulation in R may help you understand some of
the relationships and the exact value of $P(\min(X,Y) > 10).$
It is based on a million realizations of each random variable.
I have used `1`s instead of $*$'s. Approximations should be
accurate to two or three places. The first few lines of code
merely verify that the random variables have the correct moments.

```
m = 10^6
z = rnorm(m);  x1 = rnorm(m)  # standard normal
y1 = x1/2 + sqrt(3)*z/2
x = 4*x1 + 10;  y = 4*y1 + 10
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 10.00258   # aprx E(X) = 10
## 3.999907   # aprx SD(X) = 4
mean(y);  sd(y)
## 9.998794   # aprx E(Y) = 10
## 3.994897   # aprx SD(Y) = 4
cor(x,y)
## 0.4991412  # aprx Cor(X,Y) = 1/2
w = pmin(x,y) # a million realizations of min(X,Y)
mean(w > 10)
## 0.333126   # aprx P(W > 10) btw 1/4 and 1/2
```

The scatterplot below shows 30,000 simulated $(X, Y)$ points,
suggesting the density function of their joint multivariate normal
distribution.
The (roughly 10,000) points for which $\min(X,Y) > 10$ are plotted in orange.

[image]

Comment: `0.333126`... Indeed the correct value is $\frac13.$